# Get output (convert) into resource as string

Tags: terraform

My goal is to have something like a **common.tfvars** file eg:

```
users = {
  "daniel.meier" = {
    path            = "/"
    force_destroy   = true
    tag_email       = "foo@example.com"
        github          = "dme86"
  }
    "linus.torvalds" = {
        path            = "/"
        force_destroy   = true
        tag_email       = "bar@example.com"
        github          = "torvalds"
    }
}
```

Via data you'll be able to retrieve informations about the github accounts:

```
data "github_user" "this" {
    for_each   = var.users
    username   = each.value["github"]
}
```

Output of ssh keys is also possible:

```
output "current_github_ssh_key" {
    value = values(data.github_user.this).*.ssh_keys
}
```

But how can i get the SSH keys from output into a resource like:

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "deployer" {
    for_each   = var.users
    key_name   = each.value["github"]
    public_key = values(data.github_user.this).*.ssh_keys
}
```

If i'm trying like in this example terraform errors

> Inappropriate value for attribute "public_key": string required.

which makes sense, cause the keys are a list AFAIK - but how to convert this correctly?

Output looks like this:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + current_github_ssh_key        = [
      + [
          + "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAAD(...)ElQ==",
        ],
      + [
          + "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAGVD(...)TXxrF",
        ],
    ]
```

If you want to test this code you have to include a github token for your provider like:

```
provider "github" {
  token = "123456"
}
```

Comment: well it seams the aws_key_pair resource can only take one public key at a time

Comment: @LazyEval and how do you manage a usecase like this if you have hundreds of keys? :-/

Comment: What is the form of `values(data.github_user.this).*.ssh_keys`? Is it a list of how many values? Strings?

Comment: @Marcin i've edited` the output from terraform into my original posting.

Comment: So you want to use all these keys, or only the first one?

Comment: @Marcin all the keys, yep. Goal is to have one tfvars file wich is filled with user-infos, like described and "aws_key_pair" should be used to create a resource for every key behind `each.value["github"]`

Comment: You will need to prepare new data structure for that in `locals`. Something like double `for_each` - iterate over users and over each key.

Comment: @Marcin my output now is:
`"[\"ssh-rsa AAA(...)ElQ==\"],[\"ssh-rsa AA(...)rF\"]"`

got this via:
`locals {
 for_each = var.users
 my_list = formatlist("%#v", values(data.github_user.this).*.ssh_keys)
}
`

`output "test" {
  value = join(",", local.my_list)
}`

so if there's a way to get rid of [\ at beginning and ] at the end it will be the solution.